# How to set the '/' as the default path in routing in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, url-routing, react-routing

> I have publish the UI inside the api Service, but I want to start the
>   url from '/'.But it is coming as the **http://localhost:8090/UI/**.the
>   problem is that in route config I have set the routing as:-

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
   <Route path="main" component={main}>
     <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path = "/Accession" component = {Home} />
     <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
 </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('App'));
```

Error: /UI/ is not defined in route.To solve this I have to change the route as **Route path="/UI/"**.How can I set the '/' as the initial path?

Comment: <Route path= '/' />

Comment: @AmoolyaSKumar I have written <Route path='/'> but when runing in browser by root path is coming as http://localhost:8090/UI/ as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ReactDOM.render((
 <Router history={browserHistory} routes={
  [<Route path = '/' component={Login}>
   <Route path="main" component={main}>
     <IndexRoute component={Home} />
     <Route path = "/Accession" component = {Home} />
     <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
   </Route>
</Route>]} />

), document.getElementById('App'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but <Route path="/UI/" component={Login}/> this we dont want because If I do like this then in every system we have to change that name because every one have there own publish name ,we want like this <Route path="/" component={Login}/>

Comment: error is coming:Uncaught Error: <Route> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered(…), The problem I noticed in my URL is that /#/ is not coming in my url .I don't have any idea why its not coming?

Comment: same error coming as I was getting before:- browser.js:49Warning: [react-router] Location "/UI/" did not match any routes

Answer (score 0):

> For me following code works:-

```
import { Router,Route,IndexRoute, hashHistory, Link } from '../node_modules/react-router';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
   <Route path="/main" component={main}>
     <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path = "/Accession" component = {Home} />
     <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
 </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('App'));
```

> **So instead of browserHistory use the hashHistory**